# Windows 8 Pro 64 bit RTM install error

Tags: windows-8

I am trying to install windows 8 pro RTM 64 bit edition on my machine. However, I get this error once it is past "getting devices ready 75%"  and then this error. I am installing it via USB flash drive, getting same error even with multiple USB flash drives.

Error image:

[image]

I can confirm that the ISO is not corrupt. I can run the setup perfectly fine in VirtualBox. I even used same ISO for installation on my laptop and it worked great. Finally i have reverted back to windows 7. :(

System config: http://pastebin.com/jGkS5fyb (using pastebin as this is the detailed system config)

```
 [Current Computer]
  Computer Name:                          
 [Operating System]
  Operating System:                       Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate (x64) Build 7600

Central Processor(s) ------------------------------------------------------

 [CPU Unit Count]
  Number Of Processor Packages (Physical): 1
  Number Of Processors Cores:             4
  Number Of Logical Processors:           4

Intel Core i5-2400 --------------------------------------------------------

 [General Information]
  Processor Name:                         Intel Core i5-2400
  Original Processor Frequency:           3100.0 MHz
  Original Processor Frequency [MHz]:     3100
  CPU ID:                                 000206A7
  CPU Brand Name:                         Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
```

Comment: How are you installing this? If you burned the ISO to a disk, perhaps reburn it, and/or try a different optical drive.

Comment: I am installing it via  USB flash drive, getting same error even with multiple  USB flash drives.

Comment: This looks like the ISO is damaged. Download the ISO with a Download Manager which supports resume and compare the Hashes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516

Comment: @MohammadHasanEsfahanian I doubt about it. I have used same ISO to install OS on VirtalBox as well as my laptop.

Comment: Before this error came up, did it restart?

Comment: try reflushing the image to the drive, apparently its been corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion:

Based on that HW info readout, it looks like you have two 4GB DIMMs installed.

Take one of them out and try again with only 4GB (left in the Channel A Slot 0).

If it works, install fully and then put the other stick back in when it's done.

If it doesn't work, put the other stick in (into that slot) and try again.  If that one works, you know you've probably got a bad stick of RAM.

Whenever you do end up with both sticks back in, try and get them into Slot 0 on Channels A and B.  Right now it appears they are in Slot 0 for channel A and slot 1 for channel B.   this may not matter on your board, but it used to. :)

Comment: I tried by removing 1 4GB stick and changing the RAM slots but still get the same error.

Comment: Did you try each of the 4GB sticks individually as well?

Comment: Yes. I did. Still no luck.